# Identification of a caterpillar from NY

Tags: species-identification, entomology, lepidoptera

I recently camped at Harriman State Park in Southern New York, in early October.  Upon returning home, I noticed that I had a passenger with me.

The caterpillar in question is an almost translucent, pale green color with a single reddish stripe running down the center of the back.  It is approximately 1.5 inches long, with a reddish face as well.

I tried using a caterpillar identification book, but the closest one I could find also had a split tail, which this one does not.

[image: Side view of caterpillar]

[image: Front view of caterpillar]

[image: Caterpillar on a ruler (approximately 1.5 inches long)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this picture](https://bugguide.net/node/view/33090), I'd say it's a Macrurocampa marthesia. I realize your specimen lacks the split tail, but I note that the "tails" of the larva of this species are longer in earlier instars. I wonder if this one is just an older caterpillar, getting ready to pupate? The image is a very good match otherwise, and this species does occur in the appropriate range.

Comment: That sounds fairly reasonable.  Doing a search for it gives me a [picture](http://mothphotographersgroup.msstate.edu/Files1/Live/CUIC/CUIC7975a_Macrurocampa_marthesia_cat-300.jpg) that looks even more similar to mine.  The diamond shapes on the mid-back seem quite distinctive.  

I wouldn't be surprised if it was an older caterpillar, it did seem quite pudgy.